# How to detect if my Android application has been started using AndroidJUnitRunner?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-security, android-instrumentation, androidjunitrunner

I need to detect at runtime from the code if the application is run using an Instrumented Test. I'm looking for a solution that works **without knowing the Test class**.

Comment: Why? Changing the behavior of the application when it's under test potentially defeats the purpose of testing.

Comment: I need my application to work only if under test

Comment: But why?  It sounds like you're deliberately trying to get some broken code past automated tests.  In other words, it sounds like you're trying to sabotage a project.  It would be irresponsible to help you without an explanation.

Comment: Could not I just be a researcher? Or a security fan? It could be a thousand of reasons and instead of writing this things, I could just look for a loophole and tell you something like "I'm a university professor and I teach Mobile Application. I need to know if my students can somehow succeed in bypassing my tests". Even though such a thing is credible, you may continue doubt my good intentions, so why do you seek explanations?

Answer (score 0):

You can read logcat logs in launcher activity of your application under test and find the instrumented test launch command in logs.